# Как в собранном JAR файле обратиться к другому пакету?

Tags: java, maven

Собрал проект при помощи Maven получилась следующая структура:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В папке app у меня находятся основные классы, в папке xslt ресурсы, которые нужны для работы приложения.

Проблема заключается в следующем, если в IDE указать путь так:

```
File F = new File(Main.class.getResource("../xslt").toString());
```

То папка xslt находится правильно, но после сборки и запуске JARника выскакивает `NullPointerException`. Как в собранном JAR файле обратиться к другому пакету?

Comment: Встречный вопрос: как собирается jar и как он выглядит изнутри?

Comment: как-то все плоховато у вас выглядит, сбростье всю структуру прожекта (папку где лежит pom.xml + все вложенные)

Answer (score 1):

При сборке приложений с использованием мавена обычно пакеты автоматически подключаются к приложению и их достаточно просто импортировать (100% работает так в idea). Попробуй не подключать их вручную, а просто сделать import

Comment: В  этом пакете находятся не классы, а просто файлы и я хочу понять как в процессе выполнения программы можно обратиться к этому пакету.
P.S импорт работает только для классов или я что то не знаю?

Comment: Нет, просто я неверно понял вопрос